# include bootstrap modal template with template tags

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-forms, django-templates

I'm trying to create a bootstrap modal that can be included in my html files since I'm putting forms in modal and I don't want to create a new mdoal everytime.

It works fine, except for trying to include the form. Which is of course the important part. How could I include a template context variable inside a template tag?

modal_base

```
 {% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<div id="{{ modal_form_id }}" class="modal fade" ariahidden="True">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">X</a>
                <h1 style="text-align:center;">
                    {{ modal_form_title }}
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form method="{{modal_form_method|default:'POST'}}" action="{{modal_form_action}}">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ form|crispy }}
                    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Create"/>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">
                    Cancel
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Example include in some html file:

```
 {% include 'modal_form.html' with modal_form_id="new-category" modal_form_title="Create a New Category" modal_form_method="POST" modal_form_action="/home/" form={{category_form}} %}
```

form = {{category_form}} is the issue. Is there a way to get around this?
The modal renders fine, opens closes etc I just can't pass in the form

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're close! the only thing missing is that you don't need the curly braces to include it within the include tag

```
{% include 'modal_form.html' with modal_form_id="new-category" modal_form_title="Create a New Category" modal_form_method="POST" modal_form_action="/home/" form=category_form %}
```

Comment: Nice works perfectly! Cant believe I missed that should have been just a bit more patient before posting. Accepting when I can

Comment: @Slayer - No worries, this goes for any other django tag you're trying to use another one inside of also