# Django modal form

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, django-forms

I'm new to Django and this post was very interesting for my needs

[include bootstrap modal template with template tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35420270/include-bootstrap-modal-template-with-template-tags)

a) Could anyone explain me how to save the modal data without saving the form "behind" the modal ?

b) I have a form to create an Item and want to select a category. If that category does not exist, I would like to popup a modal to create it without having to leave the creation process of my Item (and actualise my selection field). Thanks to Pythonista I got the modal form, but do not know how to save and include the new value to my selection

Can anyone help me ?